# EXCEL external data connection refresh on opening on protected sheet

Tags: vba

Using VBA, how may I refresh external data connection on opening a protected sheet?

On an unprotected sheet the data refreshes great. How do I do it on a protected sheet?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a trigger or macro to execute the refresh function or do you create a button in order to execute it?

If so, on your button, let's say **REFRESH** button, insert a simple macro that will unprotect the sheet and after connecting, you can enable the protection afterwards..

Comment: Hi - no, in the properties of the external data there's a setting to refresh on opening.

Comment: ... but this won't work on a protected sheet - Thanks!